# Lotus Notes remove a header field before exporting as EML

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm trying to export a mail message as EML but I want to strip a specific header field.

This code should remove all fields that contain the string `$FolderRef`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    MIMEHeader header = (MIMEHeader)headers.elementAt(i);
    if (header.getHeaderName().compareTo("X-Notes-Item") == 0 && header.getHeaderValAndParams().contains("$FolderRef")) {
        header.remove();
    }
}
```

Afterwards the mail is written to a stream and saved as an EML file, but the line with `$FolderRef` is still there.

How can I remove this headers before saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `$FolderRef` item before converting the note to a mime stream should work.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. Unfortunately only removes the header fields if the document is saved, but some documents can't be saved (?) and I don't want to modify the original mail, only the exported EML file.

I resorted to reading the stream and removing the affected lines.